# Auto-compilation of source files in a particular directory using Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw

**Circumstance**:
I'm currently using MinGW (TDM-GCC) with makefiles to learn openGL from the book "OpenGL Superbible, ed. 5".

The sample programs of the book depend on the headers for custom tools created by the author. These headers are provided in the code bundle. The headers all use each other. So you never know (without top to bottom, line by line inspection of each header 500+line header file, of course), which other header files are invoked when you include one header file.

The thing is, a lot of these headers also have corresponding .cpp files that carry implementations of the header content. Whenever a header is used (either directly included in my code or included in some other header I included in my code), whose source file I didn't include in the OBJ (source file) variable of the Makefile, it gives error.

**Question**:
How do I configure my Makefile such that
1. I can put all the .cpp files of those headers in one directory.
2. Whenever a header is used whose .cpp is needed, the corresponding .cpp file is automatically detected from that directory and included for compilation.

**Note**: I've already used the method of simply placing each of these source files in the OBJ Makefile variable and yes it works. I'm simply looking for a better solution. And I intend to stick to Makefiles only. So switching to some IDE is not the answer I'm looking for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So this is not C, but C++.

Comment: Last I checked, C too uses makefiles as well as separate declaration and implementation files.

Comment: 1) Being rude will not get you anywhere. 2) Be careful who you accuse! You don't even know who DVed! Hint: It was **not** me. Which makes **you** - what? 3) The question is not related to the programming language itself; it is just about make, so actually no language-tag at all is rectified 4) Apparently I'm not the only one to think the question is OT 5) If you reply to a specific user, address your comment properly. Learn the rules, see the FAQ. 6) `grep` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer**

Don't do it, it's not worth the effort - IMHO

**Long answer**

The following assumes your environment is a UNIX derivative.

Gcc [supports a flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options), **-H**, that prints out header names as they are used. You can capture them, filter out system headers, etc, derive a .cpp filename for each, and compile those at some point in your makefile, using grep/sed/awk or some such. Learning how to use all that may take you longer than going through your C++ exercises.

Alternatively, you can compile all the provided .cpp files **once** into a static library, and then link with it in your makefile.

Note that on most systems unused object files are discarded by the linker, so compiling all these extra files doesn't do anything to the final executable, doesn't make it bigger, etc

Finally, you may want to install [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org) (if it's available on your platform), it's a program that greatly speeds up c/c++ compilations. No changes to makefile required in this case, just compile everything, it will be quick after the 1st time.